# почему выводятся разные поля классов?

Tags: java, классы, static

```
public class Solution {
    int i = 0;
    public static class B extends Solution {
        int i = 1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Solution f = new B();
        B d = new B();
        System.out.println(f.i);
        System.out.println(d.i);
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему бы собственно им не выводиться?

Comment: Не могу понять почему не выводится поле класса В в каждом случае? ссылка же на него

Answer (score 2):

К счастью, а может и к сожалению в Java нельзя переопределять значения поля (на самом деле вы просто создаете новое поле с таким же именем), как это делается с методами. Поэтому если тип переменной Solution то и поле будет браться из реализации Solution.

```
public class Solution {
    int i = 0;
    int get(){
        return i;
    }

    public static class B extends Solution {
        int i = 1;
        int get(){
            return i;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution f = new B();
        B d = new B();
        System.out.println(f.i);
        System.out.println(d.i);
        System.out.println("-----------");
        System.out.println(f.get());
        System.out.println(d.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем тогда вообще такая запись нужна где A a = new B(); ? на ум приходит только одно - если очень много строгих конструкторов и полей, чтобы не засорять код мы его выносим в другое место.

Comment: Чаще всего это сделано для реализации полиморфизма, часто A это вообще общий интерфейс (например интерфейс `Animal` с методом `say()`, а сама реализация метода лежит уже в `Cat`, `Dog`). Таким образом можно даже создавать список `List<Animal>` в котором будут животные с разной реализацией разговора (кто-то гавкает, кто-то мяукает и тд). Можете подробнее почитать про полиморфизм на просторах интернета.

Comment: Блин точно ) спасибо.